# Collision detected, but bugs - can get inside and not affected platforms move

Tags: java, collision-detection

Please, look at this GIF: [image]

Collision is detected properly, but those glitches annoy me... Rectangle is able to get inside another rectangle. When rectangles collides on x-axis (and right-left arrow is still presesd) one not affected is moving.
Any ideas how can I get rid of them?
keyPressed, keyReleased, move() and checkCollision() methods:

```
@Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
                int key = k.getKeyCode();
                switch (key) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        left = true;
                        game.physic.xVel = 2;
                        break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        right = true;
                        game.physic.xVel = 2;
                        break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
//jump
                        break;

                default:
                        break;
                }

        }
        /*
         * game.lvl1.getX()[i] to ablica z współrzędnymi platform
         */
        public void move() {
                if (left) {
                        switch (game.currentLevel()) {
                        case 1:
                                for (int i = 0; i < game.lvl1.getX().length; i++)
                                        game.lvl1.getX()[i] += game.physic.xVel;
                                break;

                        }
                } else if (right) {
                        switch (game.currentLevel()) {
                        case 1:
                                for (int i = 0; i < game.lvl1.getX().length; i++)
                                        game.lvl1.getX()[i] -= game.physic.xVel;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        public void checkCollision() {
                switch (game.currentLevel()) {
                case 1:
                        for (int i = 0; i < game.lvl1.getX().length; i++) {
                                if (game.man.getBounds().intersects(game.lvl1.getBounds(i))) {
                                        if (game.man.getBounds().getY() < game.lvl1.getBounds(i)
                                                        .getY() && !game.man.isOnGround) {
                                                /*
                                                 * collision above platform
                                                 */
                                                game.man.setyPos(-2);
                                                game.man.isOnGround = true;
                                                break;
                                        } else if (game.man.getBounds().getY() > game.lvl1
                                                        .getBounds(i).getY() && isJumping) {
                                                /*
                                                 * collision below 
                                                 */
                                                game.man.setyPos(2);
                                                game.man.isOnGround = false;
                                                break;
                                        } else if (game.man.getBounds().getX() < game.lvl1
                                                        .getBounds(i).getX() && right) {
                                                /*
                                                 * collision from left
                                                 */
                                                game.lvl1.getX()[i] += 2;
                                                right = false;
                                                break;
                                        } else if (game.man.getBounds().getX() > game.lvl1
                                                        .getBounds(i).getX() && left) {
                                                /*
                                                 * collision from right
                                                 */
                                                game.lvl1.getX()[i] -= 2;
                                                left = false;
                                                break;
                                        }

                                } else {
                                        game.physic.xVel = 2;
                                        game.man.isOnGround = false;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
                int key = k.getKeyCode();
                switch (key) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        left = false;
                        game.physic.xVel = 0;
                        break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        right = false;
                        game.physic.xVel = 0;
                        break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                        break;
                default:
                        break;
                }
        }
```

paintLevel() is called from paintComponent. And paintComponent is called from gameloop.

```
private void paintLevel(Graphics2D g2d) {
    switch (currentLevel()) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < lvl1.getX().length; i++) {
            g2d.draw(lvl1.getBounds(i));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide code for paintLevel()?

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.. cool gif btw.

Comment: What type of object is `lvl1`?

Comment: lvl1 is first level in package levels. It contains coordinates and size of each platform. http://pastebin.com/iScszVDZ

Comment: So collision detection works for the top and left sides of the horizontally moving blocks, but not for the right side. Or collision detection is done using the vertically moving block as a base, in which case it does not work on the left side.

Comment: Horizontally detection works fine only if movable rectangle is below a certain Y-coordinate. If movable rectangle is above half of platform's height, it's able to get inside. If movable rectangle is below half platform's height collision works (cannot get inside), but it's moving (it shouldn't). Hope you understand me.

Comment: I can make a GIF with all collision sides if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say that this is quite a bad way to do this. Each level should have a list of shapes and whenever your man moves you should check collision. Don't move if there was a collision, otherwise carry on with the position adjustment.

Here's a basic edit of your current code that might make debugging easier:
http://pastebin.com/Sz8gv863

If you want, I can code up what I meant before, but you should be able to do it yourself. Consider what might happen to your code when you have 10 levels.

Comment: My head is little overheated, but I'll do my best